# Onclick over a viewPager - Android

Tags: android

I'm using https://github.com/panxw/android-viewpager-indicator for the tab based pager control.

Everything works fine except the referencing part.
Non of the onclick event listener is working.

**Here is my code:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_flight_search_screen);         
    //set ViewPagerIndicatorView
    this.viewPagerIndicatorView = (ViewPagerIndicatorView) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_indicator_view);
    final Map<String, View> map = new HashMap<String, View>();
    map.put("Tab 1", LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_one_activity, null));
    map.put("Tab 2", LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_two_activity, null));
    this.viewPagerIndicatorView.setupLayout(map);

    View view =  LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_one_activity, null);
    this.buttonFromTab1 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonFromTab1);
    this.buttonFromTab1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {      
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });  
}
```

I'm not getting any exception as well so very hard to figure out whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't attach your click event on the view that is used by the ViewPager.

Here you create the layout for the ViewPager and does nothing with it.

```
map.put("Tab 1", LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_one_activity, null));
```

And here you create the same layout, attach the click event, but does nothing with it. It's not even visible on the screen.

```
View view =  LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_one_activity, null);
```

You need to do something like this :

```
View firstTabLayout = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_one_activity, null);
map.put("Tab 1", firstTabLayout );
LinearLayout xxx = firstTabLayout.find(...);
xxx.setonclick(...);
```

.

But, you'll probably have to change the ViewPager current page yourself in the click event because since you'll get the event, the original behavior might not work.

Comment: So what is the best approach for this sort of situation?

Comment: Do you really need a custom layout for the tab title ? Because I would recommend using a tab implementation that just work with the PagerAdapter alone.

Comment: i wanted something which can be implemented very easily with the ability of re-useability. So this seemed a good option to me but now because of its limitation to the global view access I'm wandering here and there ;(

Comment: Also why do you want to intercept the click on a tab ? Can't you just use the page change listener from the ViewPager to detect when someone change the current tab ?